# Ruby: 1.8.7: How do I find the indexes in an array where elements are not nil?

Tags: ruby

```
my_array = [0, 1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil]
```

should return `[0,1,2,5,7]`

via @the tin man: state.map.with_index { |e, i| (e.nil?) ? nil : i }.compact

unfortunately, that only works with 1.9

Comment: I think you mean where they `are` nil

Comment: Your question title doesn't match what your sample shows. Do you mean "How do I find the indexes of nil elements?"

Comment: lol, thanks, I got confused. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets there with v1.9.2:

```
my_array.map.with_index{ |e,i| (e.nil?) ? i : nil }.compact
 => [3, 4, 6, 8]
```

The question changed while I was answering, so this matches the question as it stands now:

```
my_array.map.with_index{ |e,i| (e.nil?) ? nil  : i }.compact
 => [0, 1, 2, 5, 7]
```

It's just a case of switching the ternary operator's values around.

And, once again, the question changed. With 1.8.7 and 1.9.2:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :004 > my_array.each_with_index.map{|e,i| (e.nil?) ? nil : i }.compact
 => [0, 1, 2, 5, 7] 

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > my_array.each_with_index.map{|e,i| (e.nil?) ? nil : i }.compact
 => [0, 1, 2, 5, 7]
```

Comment: this is shorter than what I learned from @dmarkow    state.each_with_index { |item, index| remaining_moves << index unless item.nil? }

Comment: how do I do this with ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: @Dernalia, see the added two examples

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a quicker way, but:

```
result = []
my_array.each_with_index do |item, index|
  result << index unless item.nil?
end
```